# Математическое представление x++ + ++x

Tags: c#

Как представление в программе x++ + ++x, разложить с точки зрения математики?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение

```
var t = x++ + ++x;
```

По сути, эквивалетно

```
x = x + 1;
t = x + x;
x = x + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x++ = x
++x = x + 1

x = 0
x++ + ++x == 2x + 2
x == 2
```